# PYTHON: sum of two numbers

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to find, for a list of numbers from 1 to 50, what numbers within that range are the sums of two other specific numbers from another list. The other list is 1, 2, 4, 6, 18, 26.

I'm basically trying to run a "for x in range(1,50):" type program that then lists all the numbers from 1 to 50 and next to them says "TRUE" if they are the sum of any two of the numbers in that list (e.g. 1 + 1, 1 + 4, 1 + 26, 4 + 18, 18 + 26 etc etc).

Any ideas??

Thank you!!

Matt

Comment: What have you tried? Sorry, but people aren't just going to do this for you... you post here for problems you run into if you get stuck. Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Ever-heard of fizz buzz?

Comment: to be honest i've just starting learning python yesterday so was just on here hoping for some guidance. this was one of the first problems in a book i'm trying to work through (which doesn't have answers!!) so I just thought it might be a really easy question for people on here, but it obviously isnt for me because i'm just starting out. i came up with the following myself, but i think its just plain wrong :-s

Comment: for n in range(1,50)
    x = [1,2,4,6,18,26]
    y = [1,2,4,6,18,26]
    if n == x + y:
        return "TRUE"
    else:
        return "FALSE"

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all possible pairs of numbers:

```
sums = []

for n1 in numbers:
    for n2 in numbers:
        # Add them together and store the result in `sums`
```

And then check to see if every number from `range(50)` is in your list of sums:

```
for n in range(50):
    if n in sums:
        # `n` is the sum of two numbers from your list
```

Comment: thank you! not sure that I completely understand this though - apologies, I'm a complete novice at this so am just learning the ropes. how should i define n1 and n2? or do they not need to be defined if used in the context you mention above?

Comment: ok, got it. so i've set it up as follows (sorry if the line breaks dont come out):

Comment: sums = []

for n1 in [1,2,4,6,18,26]:
    for n2 in [1,2,4,6,18,26]:
        n1 + n2
        
for n in range(1,51):
    if n in sums:
        print n, "TRUE"

Comment: when i run it i dont get any errors, but nothing happens, is there some command i'm missing in there? thanks again for your help, i really do appreciate it

Comment: @user1979071: You add `n1 + n2`, but what do you do with the result?

Comment: point taken. i've amended now as follows to try and make it clearer what sums [] comprises so that the test below has something to refer to, but i still just get no action when i run the test. i would have thought that it would look for numbers 1 through 50 in the range that is in sums[]?

Comment: for n1 in [1,2,4,6,18,26]:
    for n2 in [1,2,4,6,18,26]:
        sums = [n1 + n2]

        
for n in range(1,51):
    if n in sums:
        print n, "TRUE"

Comment: @user1979071: You gotta run through a basic Python tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

```
def solveMeFirst(a,b):
    # Hint: Type return a+b below

    return a+b
    num1 = int(input())
    num2 = int(input())
    res = solveMeFirst(num1,num2)
    print(res)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26240307)